# Caracteres especiais em planilha excel gerada no Delphi

Tags: delphi, microsoft-excel, pascal

Encontrei na internet muitos códigos relacionados a gerar planilhas do EXCEL no DELPHI. Segue o código que estou utilizando:

```
objExcel := CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');
objExcel.Visible := True;

objExcel.Workbooks.Add;
objExcel.Workbooks[1].Sheets.Add;
objExcel.Workbooks[1].WorkSheets[1].Name := 'Orçamento';
Sheet := objExcel.Workbooks[1].WorkSheets[1];
```

Essa parte funciona, mas quando adiciono alguma informação, como:

```
Sheet.Range['B4'] := 'M A T É R I A S   -   P R I M A S';
```

No EXCEL altera os caracteres especiais, por exemplo, para:

```
M A T Ã R I A S   -   P R I M A S
```

Fora os campos lookup, como:

```
Sheet.Cells[l,2]:=dmOrcamentos.ztBaseOrcamento.FieldByName('MP_DESC').Text;
```

que os dados ficam assim:

```
䡃㠠〬‰䅓⁅〱㠰
```

**Como eu posso formatar os caracteres para ficar como deveriam?**

Comment: Verificou se o conteúdo de dmOrcamentos.ztBaseOrcamento.FieldByName('MP_DESC').Text está correto ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilizei o Lazarus FPSpreadsheet para resolver o problema.
Com a função:

```
MyWorksheet.WriteUTF8Text(linha, coluna, 'M A T É R I A S - P R I M A S');
```

Segue link da Wiki para mais informações: [FPSpreadsheet Wiki](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/FPSpreadsheet)

Answer (score 0):

Tente o seguinte
`Sheet.Range['B4'] := WideString('M A T É R I A S   -   P R I M A S');`

Comment: Infelizmente não funcionou @wesleyluan

Comment: @Will Você deveria estar fazendo Sheet.Range['B4'].Value = Widestring('xxxx'), a propóstivo, qual a versão do seu Delphi? E com qual versão do Excel você está interagindo?

Comment: @EProgrammerNotFound Acabei resolvendo meu problema utilizando o FPSpreadsheet para o Lazarus. Mesmo assim obrigado pelo contato amigo. Estava utilizando a versão 2010 do Excel e o Lazarus 1.4.0